# Google App Script - TypeError - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a google sheet I have a self populating list of twitter tweets and I'm trying to filter out all tweets from the previous day.

I keep getting an error:

"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Error is on the last line of the code

targetSheet.getRange(1,1, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);

```
function FilterByDate() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Tweetz2");
  var targetSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Tweetz3");

 var TodaysDate = new Date();
 TodaysDate.setHours(00, 00, 00, 001)
 var startDate =  new Date(TodaysDate.getTime() - (29 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (10)); // 24hr + 6hr time zone diff 
 var endDate =  new Date(TodaysDate.getTime() - (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (10)); // 6hr time zone diff

  var data  = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var filteredData = data.filter(dataRow => (dataRow[1] > startDate && dataRow[1] < endDate));
   targetSheet.getRange(1,1, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);
}
```

I use this same code to filter different data on another sheet and it works fine.

This is the first time I've tried to use it to filter by date.

Date Time is column A on the sourceSheet.

I don't understand why it dosent work here. Please help!

Comment: You could debug down to the last line and see what filteredData looks like.

Comment: I used a logger to display data and filtered data.
Data shows fine. filtereddata no value

Comment: Check that every cells are the same format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

According to what you said, sheet dates are in column A:

> Date Time is column A on the sourceSheet.

And you're comparing your dates to the values in column B, since arrays are 0-indexed and you're using `dataRow[1]`.

Because of this, you are comparing a date with something that is not a date. Therefore, no element in `data` matches the `filter` conditions, and so `filteredData` is empty.

#### Solution:

Therefore, you should replace this:

```
var filteredData = data.filter(dataRow => (dataRow[1] > startDate && dataRow[1] < endDate));
```

With this:

```
var filteredData = data.filter(dataRow => (dataRow[0] > startDate && dataRow[0] < endDate));
```

Also, checking whether `filteredData` has any elements might be appropriate too, as [Rubén mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67014487): `if(filteredData.length > 0) ...`

#### Reference:

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this `var filteredData = data.filter(dataRow => (dataRow[1] == TargetDate));` to this: `var filteredData = data.filter(dataRow => (new Date(dataRow[1]).valueOf() == TargetDate));`

Comment: Afraid same problem.Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
targetSheet.getRange(1,1, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);
```

by

```
if(filteredData.length > 0) targetSheet.getRange(1,1, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);
```

---

The reported errors is very likely that occurs because `filteredData` has `0` elements.